# Postfix - Replace Reply-To

Tags: postfix-mta

I needed to replace the Reply-To header in PostFix

I have this

/etc/postfix/header_checks

```
/^Reply-To:[[:space:]]+(.*)/ REPLACE Reply-To: ${1} <sales@acme.com>
```

However the Mail header comes in as:

```
Reply-To: Administrator <support@acme.com> <sales@acme.com>
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it

```
/^Reply-To:[[:space:]]+(.*)/ REPLACE Reply-To: <sales@acme.com>
```